# get_product_from_item($item) deprecated replacement in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, opayo

I'm trying to fix some deprecated functions from this [unsupported SagePay plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sagepay-direct-gateway-for-woocommerce/).

How can I replace the following snippet of deprecated code in WooCommerce?

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
if ($item['qty']) {
  $product = $order->get_product_from_item($item);
```

I can see that this is its replacement:

> @deprecated Add deprecation notices in future release. Replaced with `$item->get_product()`

But simply changing it to `$product = $item->get_product();` doesn't work. I've also tried changing that line to:

`$product = wc_get_product($item['id']);`

But it causes an internal server error during the checkout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [**`WC_data get_data()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html#_get_data) method on **`WC_Order`** and **`WC_Order_Items`** objects this way:

```
// For testing only
$order = wc_get_order(500);

// Iterate though each order item
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {

    // Get the WC_Order_Item_Product object properties in an array
    $item_data = $item->get_data();

    if ($item['quantity'] > 0) {
        // get the WC_Product object
        $product = wc_get_product($item['product_id']);
        // test output
        print_r($product);
    }
}
```

Or with the [**`WC_Order_Item_Product get_product_id()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html#_get_product_id) methods:

```
// For testing only
$order = wc_get_order(500);

// Iterate though each order item
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
    if( $item->get_quantity() > 0 ){
        // Get the product id from WC_Order_Item_Product object
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        // get the WC_Product object
        $product = wc_get_product($item['product_id']);

        // test output
        print_r($product);
    }
}
```

**All this is working inside the the active theme php files.**

> When testing in the theme php files I can get the **`WC_Product`** object with `$item->get_product();`

---

Related answer: [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)

Comment: I originally used `$item->get_product();` but because PhpStorm was underlining it as a non-existent method, I didn't use it. It turns out that this does actually work. I've literally changed that last line to `$product = $item->get_product();` and it now works perfectly.

Comment: @LiamMcArthur I was very surprise that it wasn't working… So stupid editors that are not updated with the new WC methods … happy it's working.